# youtube data API v3 returns empty activity items

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**request url**: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?mine=true

- I used postman for this and made a request to **youtube data api v3** using the url above. It returns an empty list in case of my "brand" account/channel. I use the brand account as my primary channel and it has all my activities

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#activityListResponse",
    "etag": "jlYFzWSxnmZ8YXzm6DdHllY8jps",
    "items": [],
    "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 20,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    }
}
```

however it works perfectly in case of my normal channel (set as the owner of the brand account/channel by default)

**I have tried a few things**:

- checked the permission on my brand channel: I am the owner
- checked if the app had access: it does have the relevant access

Does youtube data API v3 not support a brand account/channel?